# Set the default value in a drop down menu where data is entered dynamically

Tags: javascript, html

I have a drop down menu which is populated dynamically. Im trying to set one of the options as the default value. Given that the options are populated in the drop down only at run time, I cannot use

```
<option selected=selected> No </option>
```

My code is as follows:

```
<div name="form.option" class="aob-div-dyn-field">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="label-section" >
            <label class="main-label">Choose your options</label>
        </td>
        <td class="input-section-dyn">
            <select class="main-input-select" ></select>
                 </td>
    </tr>
       </tbody>
      </div>
```

This refers to another file which has the enum declared.

```
enum options {
YES:"YES"
NO: "NO"
}
```

This line refers the enum "options" to the field option.

```
attribute optional option: options "option"
```

Any ideas on how I can proceed with this?

Comment: can you write the code which initializes your drop down menu?

Comment: I mean how do you load the enum yes and no to be shown in your drop down menu??

Comment: there are a couple of syntax errors as well. Assume just typos. Need quotes around the value for attribute `selected`. Or you can remove the value completely and just leave `selected` attribute. Also missing a closing `tbody`.

Comment: @SNt is correct. We need to see what you're trying to use to populate the `select`. Do you have javascript doing that? or is it a PHP script?

Comment: @EnigmaRM attribute quoting is optional in HTML5, and unquoted attributes (not containing spaces) have always been handled properly by major browsers. It's a safer choice in many regards, but the lack of quotes isn't causing any trouble here.

Comment: If you're dynamically populating the `select`, why don't you dynamically assign one as default?

Comment: @PaulRoub. Suppose that's true. Forget it's valid. Personal preference is to always quote it for consistency. And obviously the lack of quotes or `</tbody>` aren't causing issues. Just side notes for a quality post.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do what you need just declare the first selected option like you have and then loop through all remaining items below.  **Just keep it outside of the loop.** If "NO" is in your loop then just check for that and continue so you don't have a double up of options.  Example:

```
<?php $a = results_array(); ?>

<option selected=selected> No </option>
<? foreach($results as $key => $value): if( $value == 'NO' ){ continue; } ?>
    <option value=<?php echo $key; ?>><?php echo $value; ?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: I'm not using php with the html. I tried writing it outside the piece of code where the values are being entered and it doesnt give me the right results.